# TextView.getText().toString() vs TextView.toString()

Tags: android, string, textview, android-studio-3.0

Both methods do the same thing but on most forums I see that the first one is used but hardly the second. Is the second one the wrong way to obtain a String from a TextView or does the first method hold some advantages over the second as it is used more frequently ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`textView.getText()` returns CharSequence. To convert CharSequence to String, toString() method is used. Hence we do `textView.getText().toString()`. This method is widely used to get the text in string format from the `TextView`.

`TextView.toString()` on the other hand returns the string representation of the TextView object which is defined in `toString()` method for `TextView` class.

### **To elaborate with example:**

Lets say we have a `TextView` with "Hello World" as text which appears on screen.

**`textViewobj.getText().toString()` will return:**

> Hello World

**Where as `textViewObj.toString()` will return value similar to following:**

> android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{58a835e V.ED..... ......ID
>   0,0-0,0 #7f0800a3 app:id/textView}

This is in memory string representation of `TextView`.

Answer (score 1):

`TextView.getText().toString()` --

Gives the string value which we can **SEE** visually inside the textView widget.

`TextView.toString()` --

Gives the `string reference of the TextView object in the memory`. This value can be something like this :-

```
   @2848&8berx   or,
   @89jccxyzsjjx
```